# Unable to do reindex in DSE SOLR

Tags: java, solr, lucene, datastax-enterprise

I have 5 million records and I want to reindex only 1 field. Is there any method to reindex only one field(out of 5 fields) in DSE Solr.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, there is no way to do this.

What are you trying to accomplish? Reindex without delete all should keep your old index while the new one is built to avoid downtime (regular *not* full reindex in the solr UI).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have done index for five fields. Now I changed the analyzer for one field in schema. I want to know how to do reindexing for modified field

Comment: A regular reindex will keep using the old indexes until the new ones are built, avoiding downtime. Try this in your dev environment until you're comfortable with the process before doing it in prod.